# Do scope take up a slot after being combined with a gun?

Tags: zombicide

I have recently began playing Zombicide and started with season 3.

There is a 'Scope' which can be combine with 'Rifle' to make a sniper rifle. No question about the effect of the weapon, just the number of slots it requires to carry or equip.

There is a molotov which works on a similar principle, combining 'Gasoline' and 'Glass Bottle', but there is a 'Molotov' card which you replace the combination with and it'll take up only 1 slot.

However even after being combined the sniper rifle is technically a 'Rifle' with a 'Scope', so should it take up 1 or 2 slots?

If it takes up 2 slots, does the Scope need to be on the other hand or can it be carried and still be in effect like 'Plenty of Ammo'?

Answer (score 2):

No, if the scope is combined with the gun, it counts as one card.
You can see this in [the rules](https://www.zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-zombicide-season-1.pdf):

> Specific  Equipment  cards  can  be  combined  to  build  im-proved 
>   weaponry.  Take  the  two  appropriate  cards,  which  must  be 
>   already  stored  in  the  Survivor’s  inventory,  and  combine them
>   into the new weapon. This does not cost an Action, and the new weapon
>   takes only a single slot in your Survivor’s inventory. When built,
>   Survivors may immediately and freely equip improved weapons to their
>   hands.
>
> Sniper Rifle: Combine a Rifle and a Scope to get a sniper rifle. Put
>   the Scope card under the Rifle card. Now you can choose your targets
>   when firing with this Rifle

Comment: +1 for quick answer, do you remember which part of the rule book is this in? It'll help if I know where to look for as reminder during the game.

Comment: I added the section of the rules (found one online).

Comment: Happy zombie hunting ;-).

Comment: on a side note, which expansion would be most recommended to go with Season 3? I am thinking of which box to buy next

Comment: We have no expansions yet. But I downloaded some of the additional scenario's (https://www.zombicide.com/en/missions/) for extra fun.